# Printing Certain Pages in MS Word

Tags: regex, printing, ms-word

Using MS Word, is there a way to simply print only those pages which contain a certain search string.  For example, I have a few hundred pages of transaction summaries and there is a certain string that reoccurs through out the transaction report.  I can't throw a regular expression into the pages to print dialog or something?

Comment: Voting for close as not programming related.  Please check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/321618/where-can-i-ask-questions-that-arent-programming-questions for other places where this question would be more appropriate.

Comment: close++. This is not an MS office support forum.

Comment: Isn't VBA for office programming still programming?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use some VBA, which you can do entirely from within Word.  Have a look at [this thread](http://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=1247406&page=1)